# angular material date time picker transparent

Tags: angular, material-ui, datetimepicker

I have upgraded my angular from version 15 to 16 and I am getting strange results with material date time picker.
I am getting this date time picker GUI part (half transparent):
[image]

Has anybody experienced that sort of behaviour from material date time picker?. I don't know what my next step should be :
a) downgrade to version 15/14
b) upgrade even further
Any advice. I am lost

Comment: try adding styles @import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css'; in globally

Comment: I did - nothing changed

Comment: Do a functional example in stackblitz for us.

Comment: When I do a very simple project in stackblitz it looks OK. Why it is not working in big project without displaying any errors?

Comment: I have downgraded Angular and material library to version 15 and it works now

Answer (score 0):

may be your should update material to current angular version?